# vue3 reactive unexpected behaviour

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i've a reactive object, on the save function i call toRaw in order to remove de object reactivity, but, when i change the reactive object props, also the **group** object is changing....
How???

```js
const newGroup = reactive<Group>({ id: undefined, name: '', enabled: false })

const handleSave = () => {
      const group = toRaw(newGroup)
      persist(group).then(() => {
        newGroup.id = undefined
        newGroup.name = 'demo'
        console.log(isReactive(group)) //say false but the group.name value is demo
      })
     
    }
```

destructuring the reactive obj as **const group = { ...newGroup }** looks like it works, still no understand why toRaw is not working.

EDIT:

the whole problem comes from a sense of lack of control when dealing with reactive objects for example:

the following cumputed object retrieves a list from the store which is then drawn in the template as rows of a table at which click the selected element is changed of state. in the function I am forced to deconstruct records to avoid that the modification trigger the change of enabled before it is persisted
Is there a better way?
Should I make readonly groups?

```
//in setup()
const groups = computed <Group []> (() => getters ['registry / groups'])

const toggle = (record: Group) => {
    const group = { ...record } 
    group.enabled = !group.enabled
    persist(group)
}

//in template
  <a-menu-item @ click = "toggle (record)">
```

Comment: what does `persist()` do? I don't quite understand why it is a problem that the reactive object is updating.

Comment: persist will dispatch a store function that make an axios call to edit the row, i can't change the row status before the axios call that could fail for example

Comment: so you want the store (or portion of it) to be immutable while the `persist()` async method is updating remote data?

Comment: yes, in this example as you can see, i've used destructuring, but don't know if this is the way

Comment: for the sake of what you're doing, `{...record}` is the way to go (instead of `toRaw(record)`, because to raw returns the watched object, whereas destructuring just creates the copy for you. You could also do `{...toRaw(record)}`, but I don't think that will have any additional benefit.

Comment: if you look at the source (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/118502a4b88719645013c372532a9c413fcc58e7/packages/reactivity/src/reactive.ts#L220) `toRef` just returns the value of `__v_raw` (essentially `record.__v_raw`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This *is* expected behaviour, but the description may not be detailed enough and cause some confusion.

according to [toRaw docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#toraw)

> *Returns the raw, original object of a reactive or readonly proxy. This is an escape hatch that can be used to temporarily read without incurring proxy access/tracking overhead or write without triggering changes. It is not recommended to hold a persistent reference to the original object. Use with caution.*

What is happening when you use `toRaw`, is that you're getting back the original object that you passed into the `reactive` function *without* the Proxy. That means that the object is the same object (`o` and `g` in example ). `toRaw` only allows you to "escape" the reactivity/listeners bound to the object if you use `toRaw` instead of the Proxy itself. Even though the objects update, the reactivity (trickling down to DOM) is not applied.

Here is an example:

```js
let o = {name:"Ja Ja"};
let m = Vue.reactive(o);
let g = Vue.toRaw(m);

console.log(o.name, m.name, g.name);

g.name = g.name + " Ding Dong";

console.log(o.name, m.name, g.name);

console.log("Is 'm' same as 'o'? ", m == g);
console.log("Is 'g' really just 'o'? ", o == g);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

If you want to create an object that will not update the original object, the simplest way is to clone it.

Most of the time you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))`. The caveat is that you get into issues if you have cyclical references (ie. `{a:b, b:a}`).

Another option is to use destructuring `const copy = {...o}`. The caveat here is that it is a *shallow copy*. Example `o = {a:{b:"I will update"}, c:"I won't"}`, where `copy.a` is still same object as `o.a`

That would then look like either

```js
let o = {name:"Ja Ja"};
let m = Vue.reactive(o);
let g0 = {...Vue.toRaw(m)}; // destructure
let g1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Vue.toRaw(m))); // clone with json
```

Alternatively, you can also use some library that handles cloning object for you.

Comment: as always your answers are something amazing, one more thing  my fear is that it is not clear to me how to handle reactive objects once I need to use them. for example supposing to use a responsive object for a form, how should I use it to make changes before storing it on vuex or sending it away via axios?

Comment: updated with examples to create a copy. I use `{...o}` destructuring usually, because I'm usually aware of the implication of shallow copies, so I don't need the overhead of `JSON.parse`, but YMMV

Answer (score 4):

You have a misunderstanding of reactivity here. **A reactive object connects the data with DOM**, not between javascript objects, i.e. when a property of the reactive object is updated, the DOM is automatically updated.

[`toRaw`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#toraw) *returns the raw, original object of a reactive or readonly proxy*, i.e `group` and `newGroup` are still the same object, the difference is that `group` would not trigger a DOM update as `newGroup` does.

---

*Example*, UI is updated when you update `newGroup`, but updating `group` won't trigger a DOM change. However the two objects still have the same reference, which is why `group.name` and `newGroup.name` are always the same.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const newGroup = Vue.reactive({ id: undefined, name: '', enabled: false })
    const group = Vue.toRaw(newGroup)
    return {
      newGroup,
      group
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="newGroup.name = 'reactive update'">reactive update</button>
  newGroup Name: {{newGroup.name}}<br/>
  <button @click="group.name = 'raw update'">raw update</button>
  group Name: {{group.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: nice!, so one more thing, what's the best way to handle a reactive object when i need to use it in order to edit/send to vuex/send to axios ect?

Comment: If you mean isolating the change effect, you can either use the spread syntax as you've already mentioned. i.e. `group = { ...newGroup }` but this does a shallow copy. If you need to deep clone a new object, the common way is to use `let group = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newGroup))`.

Comment: so json parse/stringify is the way??? feels strange, coming from react where to mutate the state you need to set it, i fell like i have lower control

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do and what is your concern. Vuex hasn't changed that much in Vue 3, I believe. You use mutations / getters to set / get values from the store. And for axios, I assume it's okay to send the reactive object ? At the end of day, they are javascript objects but with listeners attached to update DOM. Though you might need to test it to be sure.

Comment: yes, but if i need to change the reactive object before persisting it?

Comment: Then you need to clone it if you don't want the change to reflect on your UI or internal component state (i.e. your reactive object here).

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based the article in:

https://chrysanthos.xyz/article/how-to-get-the-data-of-a-proxy-object-in-vue-js-3/

1 - First `import { toRaw } from "vue"`;

2 - In my vuex on return getters:

```
`
// getters
const getters = {
    listOperations:(state: { operations: any; }) => {
        return toRaw(state.operations);
    }
}
```

`

3 - `Browser: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Answer (score 0):

it is normal that `isReactive(group)` return `false`.
Actually in your code we have `const group = toRaw(newGroup)`

=> `group` is the original object of the reactive value `newGroup`.

=> `group` is a raw value, not a reactive value

if you tried `isReactive(newGroup)` this will return `true`

Comment: yest, but the problem is that it is still reactive, if i change group it will change also newGrop and viceversa